# Can't select view in Dashboard

Tags: dynamics-crm, view, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

Currently I'm working with Microsoft Dyamics CRM 365 and I have created 3 custom views using the SDK for MS Dynamics CRM.

I had to create them this way due to the complexity of the filters and because they cannot be made using Advanced Find. All of them are saved as Public Views and were created succesfully as well as working as expected.

However, when I create a new Dashboard and I try to add them, they do not appear in the list of views, not sure why this is happening but I haven't find a way to fix this issue.

I'm open to try new ideas and workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your "Custom View" as *Default Public View* & Publish the entity. This will make your view to appear under views list in Dashboard design page.

[image]

You are not alone. Some [discussions](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/127403) already happened. Someone has mentioned this same [workaround](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/custom-savedquery-view-in-dashboards-or-charts/).